# split a hunk in hg; change tolerance

Tags: mercurial

I use the *hunk-by-hunk* or *hunk selection* approach to committing: instead of commuting all changes I made to a file, I commit related parts. E.g. I wrote a function and a test, compiled to ensure it works and then commit the function and the test separately. For this I use built-in functionality in `tortoiseHg` and `RecordExtention` when in the console.

Now I have two edits separated by only one unchanged line, thus falling in `hg`'s tolerance of one *hunk*. I want to commit only the former for now. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The record extension doesn't let you split hunks further, but the less-standard [CRecord extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CrecordExtension) does.

Just to put it out there, but what you're doing is usually considered bad practice because it guarantees that you haven't run the unit tests on the files as they're being committed.  That, of course, doesn't apply in all environments.

If the reason you're leaving some parts uncommitted is because they're local-only changes you always in in place (passwords, paths, etc.) they're a good candidate for a Mercurial Queues "patch".  Then you'd be able to 'pop' them off, commit the whole file, and then 'push' them back on.

Comment: most of the time i smack some dirty debug code into the caller while editing the callee, and commit only the callee but want to preserve the debugs for later use, i only do my own 'micro' commits that way, squash them on upstream

Comment: Yeah, a patch queue is good for that sort of stuff too, but I get what you're saying.